# Vim with Markdown, how to remove blankspace after bullet point?

Tags: vim, markdown, fedora

On Linux Fedora, I am using Vim and Markdown.

After using bullet points. I want to go back to keep typing text. I hit enter and delete the last bullet point.

- line 1
- line 2
- 

After I delete the empty bullet point and hit enter. The new line adds 4 spaces. I want to start a newline from the beginning of the line.

It's pretty annoying when I use a lot of bullet point paragraphs.

How do I get rid of this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Do you use a ftplugin for markdown? I cannot reproduce this behavior with vanilla vim. Run `$ vim -u NONE`, activate `:filetype on`, `:set ft=markdown` and enter your strings. Default settings for markdown can be found with `:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim`. Another relevant option is `:set formatoptions+=r`!

Answer (score 2):

Indenting a new line to match prior lines is a vim option `autoindent`, `smartindent` or `cindent` which you can turn off.

---

> ```
>       *'autoindent'* *'ai'* *'noautoindent'* *'noai'*
> ```
>
> 'autoindent' 'ai'   boolean (default off)
>               local to buffer
>       Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing 
>       in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command).  If you do not
>       type anything on the new line except  or CTRL-D and then type
>       , CTRL-O or , the indent is deleted again.  Moving the cursor
>       to another line has the same effect, unless the 'I' flag is included
>       in 'cpoptions'.
>       When autoindent is on, formatting (with the "gq" command or when you
>       reach 'textwidth' in Insert mode) uses the indentation of the first
>       line.
>       When 'smartindent' or 'cindent' is on the indent is changed in
>       a different way.
>       The 'autoindent' option is reset when the 'paste' option is set.
>       {small difference from Vi: After the indent is deleted when typing
>        or , the cursor position when moving up or down is after the
>       deleted indent; Vi puts the cursor somewhere in the deleted indent}.

---

> ```
>        *'smartindent'* *'si'* *'nosmartindent'* *'nosi'*
> ```
>
> 'smartindent' 'si'  boolean (default off)
>               local to buffer
>               {not in Vi}
>               {not available when compiled without the
>               |+smartindent| feature}
>       Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line.  Works for C-like
>       programs, but can also be used for other languages.  'cindent' does
>       something like this, works better in most cases, but is more strict,
>       see |C-indenting|.  When 'cindent' is on or 'indentexpr' is set,
>       setting 'si' has no effect.  'indentexpr' is a more advanced
>       alternative.
>       Normally 'autoindent' should also be on when using 'smartindent'.
>       An indent is automatically inserted:
>       - After a line ending in '{'.
>       - After a line starting with a keyword from 'cinwords'.
>       - Before a line starting with '}' (only with the "O" command).
>       When typing '}' as the first character in a new line, that line is
>       given the same indent as the matching '{'.
>       When typing '#' as the first character in a new line, the indent for
>       that line is removed, the '#' is put in the first column.  The indent
>       is restored for the next line.  If you don't want this, use this
>       mapping: ":inoremap # X^H#", where ^H is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-H.
>       When using the ">>" command, lines starting with '#' are not shifted
>       right.
>       NOTE: 'smartindent' is reset when 'compatible' is set.  When 'paste'
>       is set smart indenting is disabled.

---

> ```
>          *'cindent'* *'cin'* *'nocindent'* *'nocin'*
> ```
>
> 'cindent' 'cin'     boolean (default off)
>               local to buffer
>               {not in Vi}
>               {not available when compiled without the |+cindent|
>               feature}
>       Enables automatic C program indenting.  See 'cinkeys' to set the keys
>       that trigger reindenting in insert mode and 'cinoptions' to set your
>       preferred indent style.
>       If 'indentexpr' is not empty, it overrules 'cindent'.
>       If 'lisp' is not on and both 'indentexpr' and 'equalprg' are empty,
>       the "=" operator indents using this algorithm rather than calling an
>       external program.
>       See |C-indenting|.
>       When you don't like the way 'cindent' works, try the 'smartindent'
>       option or 'indentexpr'.
>       This option is not used when 'paste' is set.
>       NOTE: This option is reset when 'compatible' is set.

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/78gvle/vim_with_markdown_how_to_remove_blankspace_after/), by reddit user `dutch_gecko`.

In vimrc:

```
let g:vim_markdown_new_list_item_indent = 0

setlocal formatoptions=tqlnrc
set comments=b:>
```

This worked for me.